# how to update column from another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to update es_flag column by taking a reference from another table. i want to know , is my query correct? because my reference table has 10 million records and it is taking too much time.

```
Update CP_RAJU b
    set  ES_FLAG = (
                    select a.ES_FLAG
                    from CMF_ACC_EXT_LEGACY a 
                    where A.CRMCA = B.CUST_ID
                    and rownum = 1
                )
where exists (  select 1 
                from CMF_ACC_EXT_LEGACY c 
                where A.CRMCA = B.CUST_ID
                )
```

Comment: Does that UPDATE really execute? I'd expect an error.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle (PL/SQL)?

Comment: oracle sql developer

Comment: it is taking too much time but need to confirm that first ,is this code correct?

Comment: No, it isn't. As I said, you should get an error. `where A.CRMCA = B.CUST_ID` has no access to A.CRMCA. I'd instead expect a condition referencing c.

Comment: Please avoid using local words like *crore* that are not understood globally

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `merge`?

```
merge into cp_raju b
  using cmf_acc_ext_legacy a
  on (a.crmca = b.custid)
when matched then update set
  b.es_flag = a.es_flag;
```

Code you posted *indirectly* suggests that there can be more than a single `es_flag` for each `crmca` in `cmf_acc_ext_legacy` so you're taking *only one* (you don't really care which one); if that's the case, then

```
merge into cp_raju b
  using (select a.crmca,
                max(a.es_flag) es_flag
         from cmf_acc_ext_legacy a
         group by a.crmca
        ) x
  on (x.crmca = b.custid)
when matched then update set
  b.es_flag = x.es_flag;
```

---

As of performance issue: did you index `crmca` and `custid` columns? Generally speaking, that *should* help.